# How to identify this circle edge?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to identify a circle in this picture using OpenCV in python:

[image]

I got this image using a web cam.
There is a logo inside of this gray circle also.That logo has same color of outer of circle (black)

I want to separate this gray circle and black background and draw a sharp line around the circle.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another a approach could be to filter your image with a median filter. It reduces the noise and preserve edges.  After that you can do a binarization with a fixed `threshold` (you have a nice bimodale histogram) and perform `findContours` after that. Then you could calculate the `minEnclosingCircle` or use `fitEllipse` or whatever you want to achieve.

```
# Blur the image to supress artefacts
# in the binary image while preserving edges
median = cv2.medianBlur(imgray,15)
# Do a global thresholding
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(median,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#Copy image to show binary image (findContours maipulates source)
copy =thresh.copy()

#Detect just external contours
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(copy, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
height, width, channels = src.shape

#Image for displaying contour
drawing = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype='uint8')

#No loop needed, just one external contour
#Draw contour, minimal enclosing circle and ellispe
cv2.drawContours(drawing,contours,0,(255,0,0))
(x,y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contours[0])
center = (int(x),int(y))
cv2.circle(drawing,center,int(radius),(0,0,255))
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contours[0])
cv2.ellipse(drawing,ellipse,(0,255,0),1)

cv2.imshow("Binary", thresh)
cv2.imshow("Median", median)
cv2.imshow("Contour", drawing)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image: histogram after filtering]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Here are the results with the contour in **blue**, the minEnclosingCircle in **red** and the Ellipse in **green**.

[image]

Comment: good idea..may be I can get your information for improve my code. Thanks

Comment: No.You have added only idea first.Then you have edited the answer...so,I mean about idea only...anyway,Im using Python..so,I need to convert your code. Thanks

Comment: thanks...I was able to get exact center point using this system..But,this system get any center point of the given shape.Have you any idea for detect only circle center?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean? I dont get it! You want the exact center of the shape? Sorry maybe i will get it if you explain it further

Comment: Think,If I give a circle shape it can identify center of the circle.no problem..But,If I give a rectangle or any other shape it also identify a center point..actually,this code automatically get a shape at every time.How can find only a circle center?

Comment: You can calculate some object features and build a simple box classifier to detect your circles. Or you try to approximate your contours and classify them by shape. Or you combine the two approaches. Or you use hough circles

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:
Tranform the image to a gray scale image and use Hough Circle Transform to detect the circle.
An example is shown in the opencv3.0.0 [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html).

Comment: Hough Circle is not a good system for my requirements...thanks for idea..

Comment: I want to detect there is a circle on camera feed or not exactly.using Hough Circle method I was able to detect circle with some shaking(detected circle is shaking.its not a big problem..but,I want to detect there is a circle or not exactly...How can I archive my target using Hough Circle detection method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can approach this goal:
First you threshold image, then you use find coordinates functions, max value of returned list will be your circle. Find peaks and draw circle through them.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import random
from random import randint
import math

image=cv2.imread('C:/Users/srlatch/Desktop/XtfWR.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


def f(list):
    max=[]
    for i in list:
        if len(i)>len(max):
            max=i
    return max 

def draw_circle(img,ctr):
    for i in ctr:
        img[i[0][1]][i[0][0]]=255


ret,tresh = cv2.threshold(img,40,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations=2)
tresh,c,hr=cv2.findContours(tresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
circle=f(c)


max_y=0

min_y=circle[0][0][1]

max_x=0

min_x=circle[0][0][0]


pointY=tuple()
pointy=tuple()
pointX=tuple()
pointx=tuple()


for i in circle:
    if i[0][1]>max_y: 
      max_y=i[0][1]
      pointY=(i[0][1], i[0][0])

for i in circle:
    if i[0][1]<=min_y: 
      min_y=i[0][1]
      pointy=(i[0][1], i[0][0])

for i in circle:
    if i[0][0]>max_x: 
      max_x=i[0][0]
      pointX=(i[0][1], i[0][0])

for i in circle:
    if i[0][0]<=min_x: 
      min_x=i[0][0]
      pointx=(i[0][1], i[0][0])

cv2.ellipse(image, (pointY[1],pointY[0]),(2,2),0,0,360,(243,0,214),-1)  #min y
cv2.ellipse(image, (pointy[1],pointy[0]),(2,2),0,0,360,(243,0,214),-1)  #max y
cv2.ellipse(image, (pointX[1],pointX[0]),(2,2),0,0,360,(243,0,214),-1)  #min y
cv2.ellipse(image, (pointx[1],pointx[0]),(2,2),0,0,360,(243,0,214),-1)  #min y

center_x=(pointX[0]+pointx[0])/2
center_y=( (pointY[1]+pointy[1])/2 )-pointy[0]

cv2.circle(image, (int(center_x),int(center_y)), int((center_y+pointy[0])-60),(243,0,214), thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0)

cv2.imshow('wnd', image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result of contours finding:

[image]

Max and min points:

[image]

Circled points:

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for example code.what is the max_y_f() function?

Comment: max min functions under the pictures, i just remove functions definitions

Comment: thanks...I  did it myself..I got how corks when rearranging the code...so,I learned something..
But,it didnt give exact center point..
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53F0wBGnYhdNXloNl9QMmN1ak0/view?usp=sharing